# htaccess how to ask for ALL subdirectories

Tags: .htaccess

I need to say - this directory and anything after do this.
/thedirectory/*  How would I write this?

Also I'm trying to figure out what exactly `/|$` means.  And what `!^` means.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/thepage(/|$)
```

Can someone help me with this?  Researching trying to find the answer to my questions isn't coming up with answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is about [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) and [regular expressions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#regex)

To answer `!^` first, it is two things `!` ([RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond))

> *CondPattern* is usually a *perl compatible regular expression*, but there is additional syntax available to perform other useful tests against the *Teststring*:
>   1. You can prefix the pattern string with a '!' character (exclamation mark) to negate the result of the condition, no matter what kind of CondPattern is used.

and `^` ([regex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#regex))

> **Regex vocabulary**
>   ^   Called an anchor, matches the beginning of the string

`/|$` is also a regular expression

- `/` matches a slash and has no special meaning
- `|` is a special symbol and means *or*
- `$` is also an anchor and means end of string

So `/|$` translates to: match a slash or match end of string.

Answer (score 1):

Well I would suggest understanding what you are using before using it. The condition you have is opposite of what you are wanting. You should be researching `regex characters` rather than basic .htaccess help because then that will tell you what those mean.

The `!` means not as in `if not` this page, `then`. So you need to remove that since you want to match on that page. `^` means start of the line basically. `$` means the end and nothing else after that. Don't really need that in this case.

What you probably want is simply.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/thediretory/? [NC]
```